# Streaming,Youtube and offline Video player Component for React-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, video-streaming

I m looking for a video player library in react-native that could

1) Play Youtube videos.
2) Stream online video via streaming links.
3) Offline videos saved in the device.
4) with Video control UI.

tried using react-native-video & react-native-media-controls for my app but react-native-video doesn't support youtube videos and react-native-media-controls has a buggy video control UI.

Open for an alternate suggestions for the same implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Uses Google's official youtube-ios-player-helper for iOS and Android Player API for Android and exposes much of the API, as declaratively as possible, into React Native.

https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube